# How to add a field in mongo which is present in the document and is not an empty string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have multiple documents in the collection of the format:

```
{
    "_id": "sjkhdfjksdghf",
    "voyage_details": {
        "etd": "16-Mar-21",
        "atd": "18-Mar-21"
    }
}
```

These documents can be present in the collection in following formats too:

1. **voyage_details.atd** is empty:

```
{
    "_id": "sjkhdfjksdghf",
    "voyage_details": {
        "etd": "16-Mar-21",
        "atd": ""
    }
}
```

2. **voyage_details.etd** is empty:

```
{
    "_id": "sjkhdfjksdghf",
    "voyage_details": {
        "etd": "",
        "atd": "18-Mar-21"
    }
}
```

3. There can be a scenario where **voyage_details.etd** is not present:

```
{
    "_id": "sjkhdfjksdghf",
    "voyage_details": {
        "atd": "18-Mar-21"
    }
}
```

4. Also another scenario, where **voyage_details.atd** is not present:

```
{
    "_id": "sjkhdfjksdghf",
    "voyage_details": {
        "etd": "16-Mar-21"
    }
}
```

I want to add a field in my aggregation query named **sailing_date** where I can select any one of the two dates (**voyage_details.atd** or **voyage_details.etd**) which is present and not empty.

I have written my **$addFields** in the following format:

```
        {
            "$addFields": {
                 "sailing_date": {
                    "$ifNull": ["$voyage_details.atd", "$voyage_details.etd"]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "etd_date": {
                    "$dateFromString": {
                        "dateString": "$sailing_date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Also, I am using the following aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection('bookings').aggregate([
    '$match': {
    '$and': [{
            '$or': [{
                    'cancelled': {
                        '$exists': false
                    }
                },
                {
                    'cancelled': false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            '$or': [{
                    'proforma_inv_approved': {
                        '$exists': false
                    }
                },
                {
                    'proforma_inv_approved': false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            '$or': [{
                    'voyage_details.etd': {
                        '$exists': true,
                        '$ne': ''
                    }
                },
                {
                    'voyage_details.atd': {
                        '$exists': true,
                        '$ne': ''
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    'company_id': {
        '$nin': ["ln_exports1582702220", "star_fisheries_pvt_ltd1576862831"]
    }
}
}, {
    '$addFields': {
        'sailing_date': {
            '$cond': {
                'else': '$voyage_details.etd',
                'if': {
                    '$eq': [{
                            '$strLenCP': '$voyage_details.etd'
                        },
                        0
                    ]
                },
                'then': '$voyage_details.atd'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    '$addFields': {
        'etd_date': {
            '$dateFromString': {
                'dateString': '$sailing_date'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    '$match': {
        '$or': [{
                'etd_date': {
                    '$lte': new Date()
                }
            },
            {
                'tracking.track_id': {
                    '$in': ['shipped_on_board']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    '$addFields': {
        'days_since_sailing': {
            '$divide': [{
                    '$subtract': [new Date(),
                        '$etd_date'
                    ]
                },
                86400000
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    '$addFields': {
        'bl_released_status': {
            '$cond': {
                'else': 'Pending',
                'if': {
                    '$eq': ['$tracking.track_id',
                        ['bl_released']
                    ]
                },
                'then': 'Released'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    '$lookup': {
        'as': 'company_details',
        'foreignField': '_id',
        'from': 'company',
        'localField': 'company_id'
    }
}, {
    '$sort': {
        'days_since_sailing': -1
    }
}, {
    '$skip': 1
}, {
    '$limit': 10
}
]
])
```

But, when I run my aggregate query using this I am getting an empty string parse error as follows:

> {
> "_id" : "c0ee3149-f44e-4ad7-90c5-8d508b9f61ec",
> "function_name" : "get_invoices()",
> "log_id" : "c0ee3149-f44e-4ad7-90c5-8d508b9f61ec",
> "message" : "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/app/functionality/main.py", line 3649, in get_invoices\n    "pending_proforma_inv": Invoice.get_invoices_count_by_category("pending_proforma_inv", keyword, shipper),\n  File "/app/database/InvoiceOps.py", line 115, in get_invoices_count_by_category\n    return len(list(mongo_conn[conf.mongoconfig.get('tables').get('bookings_table')].aggregate(query, allowDiskUse=True)))\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2380, in aggregate\n    **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2299, in _aggregate\n    retryable=not cmd._performs_write)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1465, in _retryable_read\n    return func(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/aggregation.py", line 148, in get_cursor\n    user_fields=self._user_fields)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 613, in command\n    user_fields=user_fields)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 167, in command\n    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 159, in _check_command_response\n    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)\npymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Error parsing date string ''; 0: Empty string '\u0000'\n",
> "module_name" : "/invoices/get",
> "priority" : "high",
> "timestamp" : 1615890895
> }

Can someone guide me as to where am I going wrong?

Comment: `error parsing date string` . add `onError ` and `onNull` in the `dateFromString ` aggregation

Comment: Can `atd` and `etd` fields have white spaces like `   ` this?

Comment: Yes, my mongo version is 3.6

Comment: etd and atd can have '' like this @DheemanthBhat